# Creating history of flows_030100.wwv_flow_activity_log

Tags: sql, oracle, logging, oracle-apex, data-warehouse

**Quick Version:** I have 4 tables (TableA, TableB, TableC, TableD) identical in design. TableC is a complete History of TableA & B. I want to periodically update TableC with new data from TableA & B. TableD contains a copy of the row most recently transferred from A/B to C. I need to select all records from TablesA/B that are more recent than the record in TableD. **Any advice?**

**Long Version:** I'm trying trying to ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) some information from a few different tables into some other tables for quicker, easier reporting... kind of like a data warehouse but within the same database (don't ask).

Basically we want to record and report on system performance. ORACLE have logs for this in tables flows_030100.wwv_flow_activity_log1$ and flows_030100.wwv_flow_activity_log2$ - I believe these tables are filled and cleared every two weeks or something...

I have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE dw_log_hist AS 
SELECT * FROM flows_030100.wwv_flow_activity_log WHERE 1=0
```

and filled it with the current information:

```
INSERT INTO dw_log_hist
SELECT *
FROM flows_030100.wwv_flow_activity_log1$

INSERT INTO dw_log_hist
SELECT *
FROM flows_030100.wwv_flow_activity_log2$
```

HOWEVER, these log files record EVERY click in the APEX screens. As such, they are continually growing.

I want to periodically update my DW_Log_Hist table with only new information (I am fully aware my history table will grow to be ridiculously sized but I'll deal with that later).

Unfortunately, these tables have no primary key, so I've had to create another table to store marker records that will tell me the latest logs I copied over -_-

```
CREATE TABLE dw_log_temp AS 
SELECT * FROM flows_030100.wwv_flow_activity_log
WHERE time_stamp = (SELECT MAX (time_stamp)
                         FROM flows_030100.wwv_flow_activity_log2$)
```

NOW THEN after all that waffle... **this is what I need your help with**:

1. Does anyone know whether one of the log tables (wwv_flow_activity_log1$ or wwv_flow_activity_log2$) always has the latest logs? Is it a case of log1$ filling up, log2$ filling then log1$ being overwritten with log2$ so that log2$ always has the latest data? Or do they both fill up and then get filled up again?
2. Can anyone advise how I would go about populating the DW_Log_Hist table using the DW_Log_Temp marker records?

Conceptually it would be something like:

insert everything into dw_log_hist from activity_log1$ and activity_log2$ where the time_stamp is > (time_stamp of the record in dw_log_temp)

Super sorry for such a long post.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer :-)

A chap on Reddit helped me realise my over complication...

```
insert into dw_log_hist
  select * 
    from flows_030100.wwv_flow_activity_log1$
   where time_stamp > (select max(time_stamp)
                          from dw_log_hist)
union
  select * 
    from flows_030100.wwv_flow_activity_log2$
   where time_stamp > (select max(time_stamp)
                          from dw_log_hist)
```

Hurrah! Always feel like such an idiot when you see the simple answer...